# How to avoid empty spaces between images of different size in an image gallery with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have this gallery:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8912/][1]
```

What I want is this:

```
[http://prntscr.com/53wz9q][2]
```

Comment: Both links go to the same place?!?!?!? http://prntscr.com/53wz9q

Comment: Then don't use columns. Columns have padding and percentage based width

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 3, I have some experience to share.

1. Firstly it's better for u to customize /control 
   css styles if you download them locally instead of using cdn(script loaded from other server);

   2.Your question seems to override the default bootstrap 3 grid padding, margin;

   Here is one live bootstrap 3 site for reference. 
   url: http://glow-raspberry.com/

   by viewing the source code you can use below code block to remove default margin and padding after css override;

supposing u have created styles such as

```
<style>
    .margin-0 {  margin:0px;}
    .padding-0 {  padding:0px;}
</style>
```

and applies to bootstrap html grid;

```
<div class="row margin-0">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-0">
    </div>
</div>
```

"col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" the value in this line should be set according to your responsive needs, according to your demo case url: http://prntscr.com/53wz9q, 
They should all be set to value 4 as 3 grid in a row (3*4=12) in all resolutions;

So in this way u balanced using responsive framework and apply your custom padding margin to remove spaces;

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: not fully correct, cause the img tag is not width:100% yet; see the above preview screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it based on

```
http://www.bootply.com/122476
```

The result:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/L45dvek9/1/embedded/result/
```